# qtcreator debug mode does not display contents of std::map

Tags: gdb, ubuntu-12.04, qt-creator

Whenever I try to view the contents of a std::map using qt-creator debug mode I get

`<unavailable synchronous data>.`

However, I can view the contents of other STL data structures such as vectors or lists. Why can't I view the contents of std::map??

**I am using:**

QtCreator 4.8.0 on a Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) machine.

GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04

gcc 4.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was fixed when I upgraded to latest version of QtCreator

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are actually using. Qt Creator versions range up to 3.1, the latest release is 3.2 beta. In any case, the context "Ubuntu 12.04" suggests that it's a rather old version.